# iOS: Property Values in Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

My singleton setup:

```
//UserProfile.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastName;
+(UserProfile *)sharedInstance;


//UserProfile.m
+(UserProfile *)sharedInstance
{
    static UserProfile *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        if (instance == nil){
            instance = [[UserProfile alloc]init];
        }
    });
    return instance;
}
```

Calling Singleton:

```
UserProfile *profileSharedInstance = [Profile sharedInstance];
profileSharedInstance = [responseObject firstObject];
NSLog (@"[UserProfile sharedInstance].lastName %@", [UserProfile sharedInstance].lastName);
NSLog (@"profileSharedInstance.lastName %@", profileSharedInstance.lastName);
```

Log:

```
2014-03-31 05:47:50.557 App[80656:60b] [UserProfile sharedInstance].lastName (null)
2014-03-31 05:47:50.557 App[80656:60b] profileSharedInstance.lastName Smith
```

Question:  Why is `[UserProfile sharedInstance].lastName` null?  Shouldn't it also it be "`Smith`"?

Comment: You set `profileSharedInstance = [responseObject firstObject];`, what's responseObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: Why is [UserProfile sharedInstance].lastName null? Shouldn't it also it be "Smith"?

Because it has never been set to anything.

This:

```
UserProfile *profileSharedInstance = [Profile sharedInstance];
profileSharedInstance = [responseObject firstObject];
```

gets a reference to the singleton, and then replaces that reference with a new object. So, you don't really have a singleton instance (you are `alloc init`ing another instance to return in `responseObject`).

Instead of changing the object that `profileSharedInstance` points to, you should be updating the values that it contains. Something like:

```
UserProfile *profileSharedInstance = [Profile sharedInstance];
profileSharedInstance.lastName = [responseObject firstObject].lastName;
```

*(this isn't ideal, or efficient, but it should work)*

Comment: Can I do [UserProfile sharedInstance] = (UserProfile *)[responseObject firstObject];

Comment: How do I assign sharedInstance the responseObject that I get from RESTkit.

Comment: Thanks.  What would be ideal in this case?

Comment: The ideal case is to make a function that would populate the shared instance, at least for your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make sense.

```
UserProfile *profileSharedInstance = [Profile sharedInstance];
profileSharedInstance = [responseObject firstObject];
```

Here your init is creating a static reference to a singleton object. Then you are overwriting it with a reference to what ever you are getting from the network.

Any call to `[UserProfile sharedInstance]` after this point won't work because the static reference is now gone.

What you need to do is create a method that will take in an object and set its values. e.g.

```
[[UserProfile sharedInstance] setProfile: <profileObject>];
```

when you create a singleton, what you are doing is asking the class to hold onto a pointer to an object for you, because this object will be referenced in multiple places, somewhat like a global variable. Unlike a global variable you cannot simply replace the object with something else. You must use getters / setters after its init to get / change values.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
UserProfile *profileSharedInstance = [Profile sharedInstance];
```

sets up your local variable and points it to the singleton

This line

```
profileSharedInstance = [responseObject firstObject];
```

repoints the local variable to `[responseObject firstObject]`

What I think you wanted was

```
UserProfile *profileSharedInstance = [Profile sharedInstance]; 
UserProfile *responseProfile = [responseObject firstObject];
profileSharedInstance.firstName=responseProfile.firstName;
profileSharedInstance.lastName=responseProfile.lastName;
```